# Running PSAKE script from the command line

Tags: powershell, tfs, powershell-2.0, psake, tfs-power-tools

I'm creating a batch file to execute my psake builds while integrating with teamcity and the TFS Powershell commandlets from TFPT and have come up with the following:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% "& {
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% Import-Module '..\tools\psake\psake.psm1';
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% try
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% {
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% invoke-psake -framework '4.0' -taskList %1 -properties @{config='%2'}
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% };
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% catch
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% {
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% . ..\tools\psake\teamcity.ps1; 
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:TEAMCITY_VERSION))
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% {TeamCity-ReportBuildStatus -status 'FAILURE' -text $_}
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% else 
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% {Write-Host ERROR: $_ -ForegroundColor RED}; 
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% exit $Error.Count;
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% };
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% finally {remove-module psake};
SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% };"

echo Build command is %COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE%

IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
powershell -PSConsoleFile "%TFSPowerToolDir%tfshell.psc1" -Version "2.0" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command %COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE%
) ELSE C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "%TFSPowerToolDir%tfshell.psc1" -Version "2.0" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command %COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE%
```

I was having problems with builds not failing in TeamCity when errors occur due to Powershell never exiting with a non-zero exit code. So what I'm attempting to do in the script above is to catch any terminating errors from the Invoke-Psake command, report the error to teamcity and exit the process with a non-zero code equal to the number of errors that had occurred. As far as I can tell the script seems fine. Running the resulting command on it's own seems to work fine. However running it as part of the batch file above with the command assigned to the -Command argument of the powershell executable it fails with the error:

> Missing expression after unary
>   operator '-'

I can't see why that should be especially since running the command on it's own seems to work fine. Can anyone shed any light on the matter? It's probably a syntax error somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, think you need to do some magic with escape charaters.
Any invocation of powershell I do from cmd I try to keep the formation as follows -

"powershell.exe -command '& {. C:\Temp\Example.ps1 -param1 hello}'"

Your complication comes from the multi line cmd variable you are trying to build up, each line as the variable is expanded will remove any escape sequences you apply.
I messed around a bit for you, but then thought.... why dont you just create .ps1 script with your script block in, saves any nasty escaping etc.

So Invoke-Build.ps1 becomes -
Param($TaskList, $Config)
Import-Module ..\tools\psake\psake.psm1
try
{
      invoke-psake -framework 4.0 -taskList $TaskList -properties @{config=$Config}
}
catch
{
      . ..\tools\psake\teamcity.ps1; 
      if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($env:TEAMCITY_VERSION))
      {
            TeamCity-ReportBuildStatus -status FAILURE -text $_
      }
      else 
      {
            Write-Host ERROR: $_ -ForegroundColor RED
      } 
      exit $Error.Count
}
finally {remove-module psake}

Then you can just dot source the script from cmd......

@echo OFF

SET COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE=Invoke-Build.ps1

echo Build command is "%COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE%"

IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% == x86 (
    powershell -PSConsoleFile "%TFSPowerToolDir%tfshell.psc1" -Version "2.0" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "& {. %COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% -TaskList -Config}"
) ELSE (
    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -PSConsoleFile "%TFSPowerToolDir%tfshell.psc1" -Version "2.0" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "& {. %COMMAND_TO_EXECUTE% -TaskList -Config}"